# if duplicata row update rows to 0 in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, duplicates

**I need to update values in column DF.EMAIL if have duplicates values in DF.EMAIL column to 0**

## generate DF

```
data = [('2345', 'leo@gmai.com'),
('2398', 'leo@hotmai.com'),
('2398', 'leo@hotmai.com'),
('2328', 'leo@yahoo.con'),        
('3983', 'leo@yahoo.com.ar')]
```

## serialize DF

```
df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['ID', 'EMAIL'])

# show DF
df.show()
```

## Partial Solution

```
# create column with value 0 if don't have duplicates
# if have duplicates set value  1 
df_join = df.join(
    df.groupBy(df.columns).agg((count("*")>1).cast("int").alias("duplicate_indicator")),
    on=df.columns,
    how="inner"
)

# Update to 1 if have duplicates
df1 = df_join.withColumn(
    "EMAIL", 
    when(df_join.duplicate_indicator == 1,"") \
    .otherwise(df_join.EMAIL)
    )
```

Comment: what is not done yet?  Or any issues with your code?

Comment: Hello Emma, actually, i figured this is a good solution but i would like to know other ways to do this do you know some other ways?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Syntax-wise, this looks more compact but yours might perform better.

```py
df = (df.withColumn('count', count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('ID')))
      .withColumn('EMAIL', when(col('count') > 1, '').otherwise(col('EMAIL'))))
```